# Brother HL-L2300D Duplex Fails (16.04)

Tags: drivers, printing

I've been using an old laptop as a print server (running server 16.04) for my Brother HL-L2300D laser printer. I installed it using the official [Brother drivers](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hll2300d_us_eu_as). Things were going fine. I regularly printed in duplex until sometime one or two weeks ago when the duplex function stopped working. I don't recall changing anything---this is really the only thing I use this computer for---I don't recall if I did any updates around that time, however.

When I attempt to print duplex, I get a "sending to printer..." and a "Complete" message, but no printed pages. I've tried (with the same results) from both Windows and OSX.

Mind you, I *can* print non-duplex items without any problem.

Any thoughts?

Comment: what driver are you using? oh and I think you need the generic pcl6 driver (hpijs-pcl5e)

Comment: I've been using the official one from Brother (added to question). Has something changed that I would need to install the pcl6 driver? Again, it has been working flawlessly until recently.